# wipefs device or resource busy

Tags: format, disk-utility

I am trying to format a drive using the Ubuntu Disks utility.  When I select and try to format the drive I get

```
Error wiping device.  Command-line wipefs -a "/dev/sdb" exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quary,0)
```

Nothing I know of us using it and I am doing this from a Live CD boot.  What to do?

Comment: ? Would probably work with a GParted live cd ( usually does ) http://distrowatch.com/index.php?distribution=gparted&release=all&month=all&year=all

Comment: try: `umount /dev/sdb` then retry your command

Comment: @KnudLarsen Please post your comment as an answer. I will then delete the community wiki answer below. (so you can get the reputation)

Comment: @Olimjon Please post your comment as an answer. I will then delete the community wiki answer below. (so you can get the reputation)

Answer (score 27):

Use the `-f` (force) option:

```
wipefs -af /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 13):

Unmount the disk and all the partitions on it:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
```

Then retry the wipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GParted live CD (or some other distribution containing GParted) to wipe the partition.

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this with details explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, in my case I had attached 4 drives that were previously in a RAID on that machine. I had never stopped the existing RAID after disconnecting the drives, so I had to:

`mdadm --stop /dev/mdX`, replacing `X` with whatever your previous RAID was.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unmount the drive. You can run `lsblk` to see where the drive is mounted, and then you can `umount` it, for example, when trying to `wipefs` on *sdc*:

`lsblk` output:

```
sda           8:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0 476.4G  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0   523M  0 part 
sdb           8:16   0 698.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0 698.6G  0 part 
sdc           8:32   1  28.9G  0 disk 
├─sdc1        8:33   1   748M  0 part /run/media/user/ARCH_202109
└─sdc2        8:34   1    84M  0 part
```

then I had to run:
`sudo umount /run/media/user/ARCH_202109`

and then, I could `wipefs --all /dev/sdc`